# An UDF-function on Spark DataFrame column: parallel execution

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

A Spark DataFrame is already optimized for parallel execution (the parallel executions are handled in the background), but the following UDF-function
applied for Spark DataFrame column's data processing runs as a single process:

```
def ComputeSimilarityValue(article_sample):

    max_sum = .0
    for keyword in keywords_string.split(' '):
        if keyword in model_vocab:
            max_sum += max([model.similarity(keyword, w) for w in article_sample.split(' ')]) 

    if not max_sum:
        max_sum /= float( len(keywords_string.split(' ')) )

    return max_sum    

udf_ComputeSimilarityValue = udf(ComputeSimilarityValue, DoubleType())

df_a_p = df_a_p.withColumn("SimilarityValue", udf_ComputeSimilarityValue("article_sample_processed"))
```

The `model` is the Word2Vec object (trained model) that should return the similarity value between the given `keyword` and the actual word of the provided `article_sample` (the `article_sample` is taking from the `article_sample_processed` column of the Spark DataFrame).

Figure 1 is a screenshot of the CPU:
[CPU when the UDF-function above is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyG9L.png)

It's not first time I have this kind of the behaviour using the UDF functions. Any ideas why the parallel execution is not applied for the actual case? 
Thank you.

Comment: How many "articles" are there in your dataframe? And where are you running your spark job? Locally?

Comment: Number of the "articles": 453474. The script is running on Google Cloud Instance via Zeppelin notebook.

Comment: It would be interesting to mention the following: if inside the UDF-function the stemming is used (from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer), the parallel execution is not applied; the same for the stopwords removing. At the same time if just a .lower() function is applied to the article_sample value, the parallel execution is running. So, it seems that the type of the Python's function inside the UDF affects the decision of the Spark on parallel/non-parallel execution (spark dataframe data processing).